# How do I obtain all primes from a certain set?

Tags: python

```
def all_primes(start,end):
    list_nonprimes = []
    list_primes = []

    for i in range(start,end):
        for a in range(2,i):
            if i % a == 1 and i not in list_nonprimes:
                if i not in list_primes:
                    list_primes.append(i)
            else:
                list_nonprimes.append(i)

    return list_primes
```

Why is this giving me an an incorrect output?

```
>>> all_primes(1,10)
[3,5,7,9]
```

How do I eliminate the 9?

Comment: Why loop over `range(2,i)` when you already have a list of all of the primes less than `i`?

Comment: Aside: you may be interested in learning about `any` and `all`.  I think `if not any(i % a == 0 for a in list_primes): list_primes.append(i)` reads better than the `for-else` version, although YMMV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a more straightforward way to do this, since you're already inherently generating the list of primes less than the number you're currently checking:

```
def all_primes(start,end):
    list_primes = []

    for i in range(2,end):
        for a in list_primes:
            if i % a == 0:
                break
        else:
            list_primes.append(i)

    return [x for x in list_primes if x >= start]
```

Key to understanding this is knowing how the `for...else` construct works in Python. Essentially, a `for` loop can have an `else` statement, which is only executed if no `break` statement was run during the evaluation of the loop.

Comment: I didn't know this thanks. Could you go over in more detail how to use the else in a for loop and what the last line of code does?

Comment: Sure. `for...else` is pretty much what was described - it's like a regular `for` loop, and then the `else` part is run if the `for` loop finishes without a `break`. The last line is what's called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 0):

Change it from :

```
        if i % a == 1 and i not in list_nonprimes:
            if i not in list_primes:
                list_primes.append(i)
        else:
            list_nonprimes.append(i)
```

to:

```
        if i % a == 0 and i not in list_primes:
            if i not in list_nonprimes:
                list_nonprimes.append(i)
        else:
            list_primes.append(i)
```

Aside: You can also consider implementing [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) instead. It's fairly straight forward to understand and much more efficient.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. all_primes(1, 10) now returns [4, 6, 8]. Perhaps 'if i % a != 0 ...'?

Comment: @threenplusone, sry, I was still editing. You needed to swap your logic because `i % a == 1` is only one possible condition for a non-prime. You should instead check to see if something IS a prime and eliminate it by checking `if i % a == 0`

Answer (score 0):

I tried going over your code to see where you're going wrong, but ended up making quite some changes and optimizations. I've commented the code so hopefully it explains itself.

```
def all_primes(start,end):
    list_nonprimes = []
    list_primes = []

    for i in range(start,end):
        # if already present in non_primes, skip
        if i in list_nonprimes: continue

        # if already present in primes, skip
        if i in list_primes: continue

        # if 2, mark it as prime. Special case
        if i == 2 :
            list_primes.append(i)
            continue

        # even numbers are not prime
        if i%2 == 0: 
            list_nonprimes.append(i)
            continue

        # only check divisibility with odd numbers starting at 3
        # and ending at sqrt(i)
        for a in range(3,int(i**0,5)+1,2):
            if i % a == 0 :
                list_nonprimes.append(i)
                break

        # if we got here, and the number wasn;t added to non_primes
        # it must be a prime
        if i not in list_nonprimes: list_primes.append(i)            

    return list_primes

start = 2
end = 10
print all_primes(start, end)
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/1tOSQkX1)